# PyPy: Severe performance penalty when using None in a list with integers

Tags: python, performance, pypy

Because an algorithm I want to implement uses indices `1..n` and because it's very error prone to shift every index by one, I decided to get smart and inserted a dummy element in the beginning of every list, so I can use original formulas from the paper.

For the sake of shortness, consider this toy example:

```
def calc(N):
    nums=[0]+range(1,N+1)
    return sum(nums[1:]) #skip first element
```

However, I got worried, that my results are spurious, because I could access the 0-th element by accident somewhere and not be aware of it. So I got even smarter and used `None` instead of `0` as the first element - every arithmetical operation with it would result in a runtime error:

```
def calc_safe(N):
    nums=[None]+range(1,N+1) #here we use "None"
    return sum(nums[1:])
```

Surprisingly, this small change led to a huge performance penalty for pypy (even with the current 5.8-version)  - the code became around 10 times slower! Here are the times on my machine:

```
                    pypy-5.8    cpython
calc(10**8)         0.5 sec     5.5 sec
calc_safe(10**8)    7.5 sec     5.5 sec
```

As a side node: Cpython does not care, whether `None`is used or not.

So my question is twofold:

1. Obviously using `None` is not a good idea, but why?
2. Is it possible to get the safety of the `None`-approach and keep the performance?

**Edit:** As Armin has explained, not all lists are equal, and we can see, which strategy is used via:

```
import __pypy__ 
print __pypy__.strategy(nums)
```

In the first case it is `IntegerListStrategy` and in the second `ObjectListStrategy`. The same would happen if we used a large integer value (like `2**100`) instead of `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyPy has got a special case for lists containing only integers---it stores them like an `array.array`.  If there is a None in it, then this optimization no longer works.

This could probably be fixed inside PyPy to allow None as a special case...

Comment: It is somehow possible to see explicitly, whether the optimized or the non-optimized version of the list is used?

Comment: Yes, with ``__pypy__.strategy(lst)``.